Script to delete a folder located in every user profile
We are performing an anydesk upgrade but found out very quickly that some of the new features do not pass along unless the appdata/roaming/anydesk folder is deleted from every user profile.
Ive been tweaking this code but cant get it to go down the list of user profiles in the C:\Users*
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -directory | Remove-Item -Path {("{0}\AppData\Roaming\AnyDesk" -f $_.fullname)} -force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Might someone be kind enough to guide me thru this?
This code just deleted the Anydesk folder from the logged in user.  We ran it thru our RMM which has elevated permissions but still no luck.

Are you sure it's being ran with elevated privileges? It may have already been deleted as well, but you can also try Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\AnyDesk"  -WhatIf  to see what it would delete.

have you tried without -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to see if it returned a specific error?

When ran thru our RMM it runs as domain admin and all computers are joined to the domain.  It deletes the folder for the logged in user as I am testing but not going down the list of folders inside c:\users.  How would I make it check each user profile directory?

I can test removing that error statement and report back.

Hi Team, Still no luck.  Perhaps I need to start from scratch.  MIght someone have something in their bag of tricks that will look in each local profile of a computer and delete a file.  I can tweak it if needed.
